# How to integrate email notifications with a desktop?

Tags: desktop-environments, email, notification, email-client

I've seen people talking about some add-ons and apps from not official repository (don't need such). Thunderbird alone didn't gave me desktop notifications, we have to open Thunderbird's window. I use KDE right now, but ready to change if necessary. I want to see notification on my desktop when new email arrives.

Comment: Which email client do you (want to) use?

Comment: @AnFi the best of course.

Comment: the best is completely subjective please be more specific

Comment: @wraith3690 001 I don't have any preferences.

Answer (score 0):

As one of **many** available ways 
you may try `claws-mail` with `claws-mail-multi-notifier`

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=claws-mail
https://www.claws-mail.org/plugin.php?plugin=notification

Comment: Will it send notifications to the desktop? Or I will have to open it's window to see if there's something new?

Comment: Why did you choose it over Thunderbird?

Comment: IMHO: it is ugly **BUT** filtering/sorting via perl script is the killer feature (see `perl` plugin).